# How to get cutom sound file to play in Apple Push Notification Service?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to play a custom sound file to notify the user. I use java apns as the third party library and I have developed a connector to connect java apns in order to send notifications to devices. I only have the file path of the sound file which is saved in a local drive of the server. To build the payload it requires a string input for the sound attribute. Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sound attribute is only intended for supplying a file name of a sound file which is already part of your application installed on the device.  You can't send a file from your server in the notification.

Comment: So if app is installed and not running then how can we play custom sound?